# Unable to run cloudctrl bash from windows - Permission Denied(public key)

Tags: cloudcontrol

When I run the following command on windows 8.1 machine:

```
cctrlapp APP_NAME/DEPLOY_NAME run bash
```

I get an error:

```
Permission Denied(public key)
```

How can I alternatively get access to CloudControl bash in Windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use the run-command, you have to provide a public-key and the SSH client on your local machine needs to be able to find and access the private-key. First check if you have a public-key in your cloudControl account using:

```
$ cctrluser key
```

Then check if this key matches the local id_rsa.pub file:

```
$ cctrluser key [KEY_ID]
```

If you have uploaded the correct key and it's available on the local system, the SSH client might not be able to find it. On Windows we recommend running cctrlapp inside Git bash and not directly in the Windows command prompt. This usually makes sure it just works(tm).